# How can I compute the coordinates of The $k$-points of Silicon?

Tags: solid-state-physics, symmetry, crystals

I would like to know how to find the coordinates of the high symmetry points or $k$-points of Silicon?

Comment: Find a plot of the band structure is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to Si in symmetry group $Fd{\bar 3}m$, symmetry group 227, as detailed in the [materials project](https://materialsproject.org/materials/mp-149#summary), then you need to use the symmetries of the crystal, implement them in $k$-space, and find out which points are invariant under the symmetries or some subset of the symmetries, up to reciprocal lattice translation.  You can find a listing of the symmetries in group 227 [here](https://www.cryst.ehu.es/cgi-bin/cryst/programs/representations.pl?tipogrupo=spg).  It seems with a cursory glance that we have four-fold rotation about each of the Cartesian axes, a three-fold rotation about ${\hat x}+{\hat y}+{\hat z}$, and inversion symmetry.  We have the $\Gamma$ point at $(0,0,0)$, with the reciprocal lattice vectors being along the $x,y,z$ directions as a high symmetry momentum.  Also there is $L$, at $(1/2,1/2,1/2)$.  But high-symmetry momenta also exist for subgroups of the symmetry group; for example $X = (1,0,0)$ is not invariant under $C_3$ along ${\hat x}+{\hat y}+{\hat z}$ but it is under $C_4$ along the $\hat x$ axis.  You can look them up [here](https://www.cryst.ehu.es/cgi-bin/cryst/programs/nph-kv-list?gnum=227).